# How to integrate my Hyperledger network with my django project?

Tags: django, hyperledger

I am currently creating a django web application that basically involves the use of hyperledger as a blockchain network. I would like to know how can I integrate my hyperledger composer with my django web application?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger offers a number of SDKs you can use. If you use something like Composer, then you can expose a REST API and then all you have to do is use this API to communicate with your Hyperledger Network.

A good starting point is here : 
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/applications/web.html

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/tutorials

Get to the point where you generate the API and then talk to it from your Django app.